# Running any sudo command produces strange output

Tags: bash, sudo, authentication

Looks that some script executes every time I run `sudo` command on my Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt update
mmap: Invalid argument
munmap: Invalid argument
munmap: Invalid argument
munmap: Invalid argument
munmap: Invalid argument
Unable to stop the stream.: Bad file descriptor
munmap: Invalid argument
munmap: Invalid argument
munmap: Invalid argument
munmap: Invalid argument
[sudo] password for username: 
Hit:1 http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
...
```

It doesn't depend on command after `sudo`, same for `sudo apt` or `sudo sublime`. And shows no errors when auth is not required. So looks that it's something about authentication.

Is there any specific script been run? Any log files to check?

OS: Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS x86_64

Kernel: 4.15.0-43-generic

Shell: bash 4.4.19

sudo is not aliased

Comment: Is  part of the command? Why is it there?

Comment: It's just CLI prompt. Command is starting with sudo. Will edit the post.

Comment: @Kulfy no, it's Acer laptop. SF314-54

Comment: What is the output of `which mmap munmap`? On my system, I just get back the terminal prompt. Have you searched the internet for `mmap: Invalid argument` or `munmap: Invalid argument`?

Comment: Same, back to terminal prompt, there're no such commands. 

Searched, there're only few posts with near same output (not exactly the same though), related to OpenCV on Raspbery PI (probably, this is the reason of Kulfy's question). I don't have OpenCV installed.

Comment: There's something called OpenALPR related to OCR: someone [reported]('munmap: Invalid argument) the `munmap: Invalid argument` error too.

Comment: Don't have OpenALPR or any OCR installed too.

Comment: has anyone had access to your computer? I was playing with a rubber ducky payload that aliases sudo with a command that ncats the entered sudo password off to another computer... https://github.com/hak5darren/USB-Rubber-Ducky/wiki/Linux-and-OSX-sudo-password-grabber... do you see anything suspicous in .bashrc or .bash_profile???

Comment: @JoshuaBesneatte yep, it really looks like something tries to steal my pw. But nothing strange in .bashrc or .bash_profile. Also, it's same if I run `bash --norc`: 
`bash-4.4$ sudo ls` `mmap: Invalid argument.....`

Comment: Nobody had access, as far as I know.

Comment: does the sudo authentication work? have you tried to `sudo apt install --reinstall sudo` ?

Comment: @JoshuaBesneatte authentication works ok. It works normally, but produces that 10 lines of errors/warnings before each pw prompt. Tried to reinstall sudo (didn't know it's possible), not fixed, same warnings after reinstall.

Comment: Have you tried locating mmap and munmap to know is there any file with this name? Try `sudo locate mmap munmap`. (sudo is used to find in root directory as well)

Comment: Sorry @Kulfy for delayed response. Here's the output: https://gist.github.com/jeka-kiselyov/7684b0cfe347d4755f11a407762d6036